# Intel Edison: MRAA javascript i2c.read() stores result as object or string?

Tags: javascript, i2c, intel-edison

When I execute i2c.read(7) the result gets stored as a string.  If I am not mistaken I thought `var d = i2c.read(7)` should get stored as an object?  I am still unclear about what the mraa Javasript i2c API is. Does the i2c.read() supposed to store the result as an object or string? If object, then what am I not doing correctly?

The console.log outputs:
**JSON.stringify: "\u00012.974\u0000"

typeof: string

Result: 2.974**

Code:

```
var m = require('mraa');
var i2c = new m.I2c(1);
i2c.address(0x63);

i2c.write("R");
console.log("Reading I2C..");

function readPH() {
  var d = i2c.read(7);
  console.log("JSON.stringify: " + JSON.stringify(d));
  console.log("typeof: " + typeof d);
  console.log("Result: " + d);
}

setTimeout(function (e) { readPH(); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of mraa (0.5.4+) will store the result of i2c.read() as a node_buffer object. It's possible you're on an old version which used to return strings, check with the getVersion() call.